# What is the purpose of the stringizer operator and how can it be used?

Tags: c

What is the purpose of the # operator, called the stringizer operator,
and how can it be used?

My book describes # in the following way, the bald part is what I do not understand.

The stringizer operator # must be followed by a parameter and **they are replaced with a string literal contructed from the argument's tokens, which are not first replaced** That is, the following input:

```
#define W 124
#define str(a) (#a)

str(W)
```

produces the output:

"W"

If we would like to have a **string literal** with the definition of a macro, we must use two function-like macros:

```
 #define W 124
 #define xstr(a) (#a)
 #define str(b) (xstr(b))
```

which produces the output

"124"

**The reason for this is that the argument of the parameter b is completely replaced before the parameter is replaced in the replacement-list of str, which means that the invocation of xstr will use 124 as the argument which is then stringized in xstr**

Comment: Think about the question, if macro expansion is eager or lazy. To help you with that, read about lazy argument evaluation in haskell vs eager argument evaluation in just about any other language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So to understand this, think of how the preprocessor will treat these things. In the **first example** we can see that

```
#define W 124
#define str(a) (#a)

str(W)
```

would get processed as follows `str(W) -> #W -> "W"`.

Now if we take the **second example** this

```
#define W 124
#define xstr(a) (#a)
#define str(b) (xstr(b))

str(W)
```

Would be processed as follows: `str(W) -> xstr(124) -> #124` and finally `"124"`

Answer (score 2):

**#a** forces the compiler to put the value of a, which in this case is a macro argument, in double quotes. This quoting of the string happens *before substitution* within the macro. Thus you get the "W".

You can see this by passing your source through the C preprocessor; you do not need to have a valid C program here. On Linux hosts, ignoring the "#" and blank line fluff produced by **cpp**, we get:

```
  cpp macro-strings.c
  ("W")
```

Adding a level of indirectness allows the expansion the value of **W**. Since there is no "#" in the outer macro the substitutions occurs within that macro before the inner macro is expanded, which creates the string.

If you comment out the xstr definition it may become more visual:

```
#define W 124
 /* #define xstr(a) (#a)  */
 #define str(b) (xstr(b))

 cpp macro-strings.c 
 (xstr(124))
```

Removing the comment produces the proper **(("124"))**

And do remember, that adjacent double-quoted strings are combined by the compiler into a single string:

```
"Hello," " " "world!"    is the same as    "Hello, world!"
```

This can become quote important when one or more strings are generated within macros.

Answer (score -2):

If time is not that much an issue, understanding often comes from a "do it yourself" approach. Here, if the question is "what is preprocessor doing?", why not write a simplified toy-preprocessor and study the results. I forgot the name, but there is a "law", saying "You only really understood if you can implement it".

Of course, writing a full fledged C/C++ preprocessor is not really attractive. So, the following code tries to get a sufficiently large, yet minimalist implementation of a simplified model, which is just so able to showcase what is basically going on. A compact language has been chosen to keep the line count low. No parser is needed if you resort to abstract syntax tree level instead of using a syntax.

```
type MacroExpr =
    | MacroDef of string * string list * MacroExpr
    | MacroCall of string * (string * MacroExpr) list
    | String of string
    | Stringize of MacroExpr
    | ArgRef of string

let rec run (macros : MacroExpr list) (call : MacroExpr) : MacroExpr =
    let value_of arg_name =
        match call with 
        | MacroCall(n,args) -> snd (List.find (fun a -> fst a = arg_name) args)
        | _ -> failwith "bla bla"
    match call with
    | MacroCall(n,al) ->
        let m = macros |> List.find (fun m -> match m with | MacroDef(n1,_,_) -> n1 = n | _ -> false)
        let mname,margs,mbody = 
            match m with 
            | MacroDef(a,b,c) -> a,b,c 
            | _ -> failwithf "macros argument contains something else: %A" m
        let rec x_to_string = function
            | String s -> s
            | Stringize x -> x_to_string x
            | ArgRef(an) -> x_to_string (eval (snd(al |> List.find (fun (n,_) -> n = an))))
            | MacroDef(_,_,_) -> failwith "No nested macros supported."
            | MacroCall(n,_) -> n
        and eval = function
            | String s -> String s
            | Stringize x -> String (x_to_string x)
            | ArgRef(an) -> String (x_to_string (snd(al |> List.find (fun (n,_) -> n = an))))
            | MacroDef(_,_,_) -> failwith "No nested macros supported."
            | MacroCall(n,al1) ->
                run macros (MacroCall(n, al1 |> List.map (fun (an,ax) -> an,eval ax)))

        match mbody with
        | ArgRef(an) -> snd(al |> List.find (fun (n,_) -> n = an))
        | Stringize(x) -> String(x_to_string x)
        | String s -> String s
        | MacroCall(mn,al1) ->
            run macros (MacroCall(mn, al1 |> List.map (fun (an,ax) -> an,eval ax)))
        | MacroDef(_,_,_) -> failwithf "No nested macros supported. Found one in %s: %A" n mbody
    | _ -> failwithf "'call' argument shall be a MacroCall expression but is a %A" call


let macros =
    [
        MacroDef ("W", [], String "124")
        MacroDef ("str1", ["a"], Stringize (ArgRef "a"))
        MacroDef ("str2", ["a"], MacroCall("str1", ["a",ArgRef "a"]))
    ]

let calls =
    [
        MacroCall("W",[])
        MacroCall("str1",["a",MacroCall("W",[])])
        MacroCall("str2",["a",MacroCall("W",[])])
    ]


calls
|> List.map (fun c -> run macros c)
```

The `macros` variable contains the list of predefined macros we want to explore. They are defined in terms of the (minimal, low tech) `MacroExpr` type.

The `calls` variable contains a list of macro invocations, using the same technique.

Even if we ignore the implementation of the function `run` for now, we see something interesting:

The macro definition for "str2" forwards its argument 'a' to a macro call to str1. An ArgRef - a reference to the argument list of "str2". Languages which follow the eager evaluation principle will not pass that ArgRef down to the next macro evaluation but instead attempt to resolve it first. After all, else the evaluation of "str1" would have to know about the arglist of the caller "str2".

Hence, the argument for the call of str1 from str2 is `["a",MacroCall("W",[])]`, whereas a direct invocation of macro str1 with `["a",MacroCall("W",[])]` is first resolved by evaluating the macro "W" to `String "124"`.

The last 2 lines in the code run all calls and the results yielded are not as expected:

> val it : MacroExpr list = [String "124"; String "124"; String "W"]

Now, as an exercise, you could try to change the run function such, that it behaves as the c preprocessor does. Tip: sub-functions `x_to_string` and `eval` are the culprits ;)

The fixed version of those 2 sub-functions is:

```
    let rec x_to_string = function
        | String s -> s
        | Stringize x -> x_to_string x
        | ArgRef(an) -> x_to_string ( (*eval*) (snd(al |> List.find (fun (n,_) -> n = an)))) // disabled eval
        | MacroDef(_,_,_) -> failwith "No nested macros supported."
        | MacroCall(n,_) -> n
    and eval = function
        | String s -> String s
        | Stringize x -> String (x_to_string x)
        | ArgRef(an) -> String (x_to_string (eval (snd(al |> List.find (fun (n,_) -> n = an))))) // added eval
        | MacroDef(_,_,_) -> failwith "No nested macros supported."
        | MacroCall(n,al1) ->
            run macros (MacroCall(n, al1 |> List.map (fun (an,ax) -> an,eval ax)))
```

... and now the result is as expected:

> val it : MacroExpr list = [String "124"; String "W"; String "124"]